# Google Maps API doesn't show the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm working on a project and I need to use a google maps API and I saw a few tutorials, read the documentation, and saw the code once. Once again I don't see a mistake.

**Code**

```html
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div>

            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

             <script type="text/javascript">

             var map;

                function ini()
                {
                    var mapOptions =
                    {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831, -122.4039),
                        zoom: 12,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }

                    map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                }

    </script>
```

If somebody know how to fix it, would appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you calling the `ini` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined function ini but didn't call it. The solution might look like this.

```
var map;

ini();

function ini()
{
    var mapOptions =
        {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831, -122.4039),
           zoom: 12,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

    map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

**Edit**

Following the example from google the right way is to set up callback function

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=ini"
    async defer></script>
```

Should work just right. If you will have any further problems check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)